# System Overlay not covering Status bar & Navigation bar Android

Tags: android, android-windowmanager

I am using Window Service to draw Overlay over screen. But my Overlay not covering the whole screen, It leaves out Status bar and Navigation Bar.
I have tried different approaches to solve it, but didn't find any solution. But the solution is available, as some Apps (Edge Lighting) on Play Store drawing border over full screen(Even on Android O).

My code snippet to achieve the task.

1. Window Manager

   ```
       int Layout_Flag;

   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
       Layout_Flag = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY;
   }else {
       Layout_Flag = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT;
   }

   final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
           WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
           WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
           Layout_Flag,
           WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED,
           PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
   params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
   windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
   windowManager.addView(customView, params);
   ```
2. Drawing Edge

   `override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
   super.onDraw(canvas)
   // draw a shape
   val width = measuredWidth
   val height = measuredHeight

   ```
    val strokeWidthCalculation = paint.strokeWidth / 2
    path?.moveTo(strokeWidthCalculation, strokeWidthCalculation)
    path?.lineTo(width - strokeWidthCalculation, strokeWidthCalculation)
    path?.lineTo(width - strokeWidthCalculation, height - strokeWidthCalculation)
    path?.lineTo(strokeWidthCalculation, height - strokeWidthCalculation)
    path?.close()

    paint.pathEffect = cornerPathEffect
    canvas.drawPath(path!!, paint)
   ```

   }`
3. Result
   [sample image, not covering status and navigation bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRzRs.jpg)

Comment: I have met the same problem, did you solved it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to achieve it, the fourth parameter of `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS`.

That's it.

The whole complete code:

```
val LAYOUT_FLAG: Int
    LAYOUT_FLAG = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY
    } else {
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST
    }
    params = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LAYOUT_FLAG,  // NOTE
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
                or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
    )
```